# Need to set reuseIdentifier, but not possible

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tableview

my App is kind of a `FileManager` like the `Finder` under `MAC` `OS`. I can show up the root of the filesystem. But the `Navigation` through the directories makes problems.

In the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i create a new instance of the current TableViewController. I set the `Delegate` and `DataSource` to`self`. Now the Problem that i have: The TableViewCells of the new created instance do not have a resueIdentifier. The value is NULL. And i cant set it because its read-only. So, how can i get the new cells to have a specific reuseIdentifier?

Below is my Code from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`- Method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator)
{
    NSLog(@"Entered Directory");
    NSLog(@"reuseIdentifier: %@",cell.reuseIdentifier); // <- value: "fileCell"

    FileTableViewController *newDir = [[FileTableViewController alloc] init];

    newDir.tableView.dataSource = self;
    newDir.tableView.delegate = self;

    [newDir setDirectory:cell.textLabel.text];

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [newDir.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSLog(@"reuseIdentifier NewCell: %@",newCell.reuseIdentifier);  // <- is NULL

    //[newDir setTitle: [fileManager currentDirectoryPath]];


    /*[self setDirectory:cell.textLabel.text];
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [fileManager currentDirectoryPath]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    */


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newDir animated:YES];
}

      }
```

if you need more Code to help me, just let me know.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: i'm getting the following error message:`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier fileCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Try setting the identifier from the properties inspector.

Comment: I have to create my FileTableViewController programatically, so i dont have it in the stoyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm too late with this answer. But here're my thoughts.

```
UITableViewCell *newCell = [newDir.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 NSLog(@"reuseIdentifier NewCell: %@",newCell.reuseIdentifier);  // <- is NULL
```

It is NULL because the tableView is not created. It will be created just after you make a push.
If you want to pass some params to your table, you should implement the variables in the FileTableViewController.h, and then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` make use of this like:

```
FileTableViewController *newDir = [[FileTableViewController alloc] init];
newDir.SomeData = cell.textLabel.text;
```

One more important thing - if the FileTableViewController is a UITableViewController, you should not  set the `dataSource` and `delegate`, especially in your current viewController. Because doing this, you set `delegate` to self of current viewController (not the FileTableVC that was created). 
Otherwise, if FileTableVC is not UITAbleViewController Class, you should make the delegate and datasource in FileTableVC's viewDidLoad.